# RabbitMQ channel closes, no error, connection remains

Tags: javascript, typescript, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I'm having a weird problem where a channel on a connection is closed unceremoniously and I can't track it down. What would cause a channel to be closed without an error being raised?

- The application is running in kubernetes
- The application is consuming on a queue, but doesn't appear to be doing anything when the channel is closed. In one instance, the application starts consuming on the queue and about 19 minutes later, the channel is closed. The application was inactive during that time.
- Handlers exist on

  - `connection.on('error')`
  - `connection.on('close')`
  - `channel.on('error')`
  - `channel.on('close')` <-- only this is being emitted
- No application code exists that would call `channel.close()`
- RabbitMQ server logs do not indicate that the server initiated the close of the channel
- `amqplib` 0.10.3

UPDATE

I've added channel reconnection logic. My consideration is that since the channel close event is the only event being raised, that the connection is still valid. However, I get `IllegalOperationError: Connection closed (Error: read ECONNRESET)` when attempting to create the channel. So I have a channel closed event, no connection closed event, but the connection is also closed.

There is still no correlating evidence on the RabbitMQ server side. I'm going to be updating instance to log more connection and channel details on the `debug` level and see what we get.